# How to pass data values to other ViewController Objective-C using NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'm following a tutorial from a book and everything went fine untill i had to recieve the data from the tableView, i must mention that i modified some of the basic tutorial to fit my needs as i work with JSON values comming from a API. It crashes when i reference the value using **self** and says that the variables is nil. must also mention that the label has been added as a reference outlet and the `customClass` also as been created and added referenced with the View. Aditional to this added properly Segue to the `detailViewController`

**UserDetailViewController.h**

```
@interface UserDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *labelName;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *detailLabelName;

@end
```

**UserDetailViewController.m**

This is the code that does the transition between Table and `detailView` but there are a few values that does not belong to the code i have such as `recipeName` and `recipeNames` as you can see below:

`recipeName` is on my code `labelName`
`recipeNames` is on my code a dictionary `[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"]`

and have no idea how to put this part together. :(

// Here is where I handles the Data Transfer

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"userDetailView"])
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.recipeName = [recipeNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
}
```

Comment: What i need is to labelName that is from the tableView change the value of detailLabelName

Comment: Where are you setting the labelName?

Comment: on userdetailviewcontroller.h

Comment: No i mean where are u setting the value for labelName. It seems that labelName is not initialised and hence its coming as nil.

Comment: Adding Variables to the Custom Class
class by extending from the UIViewController class. However, it doesn’t differ from the parent class until we add our own variables and methods. There are a couple of things we have to change:
• Assign a variable (recipeName) for data passing – when user selects a recipe in the Recipe view, there must be a way to pass the name of recipe to the detail view.
• Assign an outlet variable (recipeLabel) for the text label – presently the label is static. It should be updated as the name of recipe changes.
add variables. on “RecipeDetailViewController.h”

Comment: please show us the code where you assign `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *labelName;`. I assume you do that in the previous' view controllers `prepareForSegue` method?

Comment: @Argent its on the Question UserDetailViewController.h the prepareForSegue should it pass the value right?

Comment: uuhm.. in your `prepareForSegue` method you are setting a property on a `RecipeDetailViewController` but in your question you are asking about the `UserDetailViewController`. Is it possible that you mixed up your ViewController names?

Comment: this is the tutorial im following https://www.dropbox.com/s/uj6nzej8n3v3ibd/RecipeAppDataPassing.zip is the same but the only difference is that i work with JSON and the other is a Array

Answer (score 2):

According to my understanding, you want to set text for `detailLbelName` depending on labelName. And this value is coming from your parent view controller.

You must be doing something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UserDetailViewController *detailController = [[UserDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UserDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.detailController.lableName = @"Your Text According to Cell"
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
}
```

In your `UserDetailViewController`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear
{

    self.title = self.labelName;

    [self.detailLabelName setText:self.labelName]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To receive the data from tableView need to handle tableView delegate did select method and passed all required data to detailLabelName then refresh the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Move the assignment lines in viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear
{

self.title = self.labelName;

_detailLabelName.text = _labelName; // this is the breakpoint
}
```

Then, hwever you are storing the string in the table view (i assume you mean the cells specifically) then you may assign the value extracted from the table view cell after creating the detail view controller but before it is pushed onto the navigation stack and crashes your app.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

In

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

of your table view do this.

```
    UserDetailViewController *detailsView = [[UserDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:"Your nib name" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UITableViewCell *reqDcell =  [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    detailsView.labelName = //Text from reqDcell goes here. In particular the recipe name
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableViewControls animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps.

************** EDIT ****************

Ok so inorder to pass values using a dictionary , you would need an array of dictionaries which hold your data.

In terms of the link you posted, i have modified it for your understanding to use dictionaries.

```
recipeNames = @[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Mushroom" forKey:@"Recipie Name"],
                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Hamburger" forKey:@"Recipie Name"],
                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Pasta" forKey:@"Recipie Name"],
                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Pizza" forKey:@"Recipie Name"],
                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Noodles" forKey:@"Recipie Name"]];
```

The dictionary here will hold the json data that you have.

in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
// Display recipe in the table cell
    NSDictionary *dict = [recipeNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = [dict valueForKey:@"Recipie Name"];
```

and the prepareForSegue function.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSDictionary *dict = [recipeNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.recipeName = [dict valueForKey:@"Recipie Name"];
    }
}
```

I hope this is helpful

Comment: as I look I think is the PrepareForSegue thats why is not passing the value. but since I'm not using arrays but dictionary it does not work properly. I will edit my Question so you could see.

Comment: @eddwinpaz Yes please.. and AFAIK there shouldn't be any problem in passing values with dictionaries.

Comment: I get this error on the Console Log: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'showUserDetail'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

Comment: But the Segue is set up.

Comment: If i use Push it wont work but if i change it to Modal it passes the value but does not show the Navegation Controller. Any ideas?

Comment: Now I'm able to pass the data to the other view using your help, But i had to change the Segue to Modal Instead of Push and it works. But now the NAvegation controller does not appear so i cannot go back to the TableView. Can you guide me please? thanks.

Comment: @eddwinpaz: Hmmm.. I do not know why it is not working for push. The same changes I have implemented it in push presentation style only.

Comment: I solved the Issue with the push, i had selected the table view instead of tableView controller as initial controller. Thanks for your time to keep up the question. Have a nice day.